# Pad an integer using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regular expressions with a python framework to pad a specific number in a version number:

10.2.11

I want to transform the second element to be padded with a zero, so it looks like this:

10.02.11

My regular expression looks like this:

```
^(\d{2}\.)(\d{1})([\.].*)
```

If I just regurgitate back the matching groups, I use this string:

```
\1\2\3
```

When I use my favorite regular expression test harness (http://kodos.sourceforge.net/), I can't get it to pad the second group.  I tried \1\20\3, but that interprets the second reference as 20, and not 2.

Because of the library I'm using this with, I need it to be a one liner.  The library takes a regular expression string, and then a string for what should be used to replace it with.

I'm assuming I just need to escape the matching groups string, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about removing the `.` from the regex?

```
^(\d{2})\.(\d{1})[\.](.*)
```

replace with:

```
\1.0\2.\3
```

Comment: I love the "outside of the box" thinking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about a completely different approach?

```
nums = version_string.split('.')
print ".".join("%02d" % int(n) for n in nums)
```

Comment: I feel compelled to upvote simple Python solutions that are regex-free.  (It would probably be a different story if it were Perl.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(^\d(?=\.)|(?<=\.)\d(?=\.)|(?<=\.)\d$)
```

And replace the match by `0\1`. This will make any number at least two digits long.

Comment: this didn't match my string: 10.2.11

Comment: It works for me: `re.compile(r"(^\d(?=\.)|(?<=\.)\d(?=\.)|(?<=\.)\d$)").sub(r"0\1", "10.2.11")`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your library support [named groups](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups)?  That might solve your problem.